# error with __security_init_cookie when using an imported function in a dll

Tags: c++, dll, dllexport

I'm trying to import an fonction from an dll using VS2010 with this code

```
 // test.cpp : définit le point d'entrée pour l'application console.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
#include<map>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

namespace mido{
class ABC_YieldCurve;

}


typedef int (*buildDepoSwapCurve)(mido::ABC_YieldCurve *& depoSwapTermStructure, long asOfDate, 
    std::map<std::string, double>& depoInstruments, std::map<std::string, double>& swapInstruments, std::string& error );

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    buildDepoSwapCurve mybuildDepoSwapCurve;
    HINSTANCE hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("YieldCurve.dll"));
    if (hinstLib == NULL) {
                printf("ERROR: unable to load DLL\n");
                cin.get();
                return 1;
        }

     mybuildDepoSwapCurve = (buildDepoSwapCurve)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "buildDepoSwapCurve");
        if (mybuildDepoSwapCurve == NULL) {
                printf("ERROR: unable to find DLL function\n");
                cin.get();
                FreeLibrary(hinstLib);
                return 1;
        }


    //Construction d'un depoInstruments 
    std::map<std::string,double> mydepoInstruments;
    mydepoInstruments["1W"]=0.0382;
    mydepoInstruments["1M"]=0.0372;
    mydepoInstruments["3M"]=0.0363;
    mydepoInstruments["6M"]=0.0353;
    mydepoInstruments["9M"]=0.0348;
    //Construction d'un swap instrument
    std::map<std::string,double> mySwapInstruments;
    mySwapInstruments["1Y"]=0.0345;
    mySwapInstruments["2Y"]=0.037125;
    mySwapInstruments["3Y"]=0.0398;
    mySwapInstruments["5Y"]=0.0443;
    mySwapInstruments["10Y"]=0.05165;
    mySwapInstruments["15Y"]=0.055175;
    mySwapInstruments["25Y"]=0.05165;

    //l'objet myYieldCurve nul
    mido::ABC_YieldCurve * myYieldCurve;
    string t="";
    cout<< mybuildDepoSwapCurve(myYieldCurve,40000,mydepoInstruments,mySwapInstruments,t)<<endl;;

    cout<<"test";
    cin.get();

    FreeLibrary(hinstLib);
    return 0;
}
```

The result shows that the import of the dll and the function are succesful.
But I can not understand why there is the error (sorry it's in french)
Exception de première chance à 0x76bdb727 dans testWrapper.exe : Exception Microsoft C++ : QuantLib::Error à l'emplacement mémoire 0x0015f800..
Exception non gérée à 0x76bdb727 dans testWrapper.exe : Exception Microsoft C++ : QuantLib::Error à l'emplacement mémoire 0x0015f800..

However, my friend use VS2008 and this code works
The error when the code stops is:

```
    {
        /*
         * The /GS security cookie must be initialized before any exception
         * handling targetting the current image is registered.  No function
         * using exception handling can be called in the current image until
         * after __security_init_cookie has been called.
         */
        __security_init_cookie();

        return __tmainCRTStartup();
}
```

in the file crtexe.c
Thanks

I've removed the Remove the /GS (Buffer Security Check) but the problem now is in the code dbgheap.c

```
 extern "C" _CRTIMP void __cdecl _free_dbg(
        void * pUserData,
        int nBlockUse
        )
{
        /* lock the heap
         */
        _mlock(_HEAP_LOCK);

        __try {
            /* allocate the block
             */
            _free_dbg_nolock(pUserData, nBlockUse);
        }
        __finally {
            /* unlock the heap
             */
            _munlock(_HEAP_LOCK);
        }
}
```

Comment: This is the CRT startup code for an EXE, note the file name "crtexe.c".  How you got that code linked into a DLL is rather a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the **/GS** (Buffer Security Check) in your project settings :)

Comment: Don't like the message, shoot the messenger?

Comment: When importing a VS[Before 2010] dll project /GS is set and should not.

Comment: Project->Properties->C/C++->Code Generation->Buffer Security Check->NO

Comment: I've just done exactly what you've said but it's the same result :-(

Comment: now the problem is extern "C" _CRTIMP void __cdecl _free_dbg(
        void * pUserData,
        int nBlockUse
        )
{
        /* lock the heap
         */
        _mlock(_HEAP_LOCK);

        __try {
            /* allocate the block
             */
            _free_dbg_nolock(pUserData, nBlockUse);
        }
        __finally {
            /* unlock the heap
             */
            _munlock(_HEAP_LOCK);
        }
}